Integral with a Recurrence Relation as a Limit - how should one deal with a case like that?
This question comes from an integration bee workshop problem set I found online. The problem states: $$I_0 = 1,\ I_n = \int_{0}^{I_{n-1}} \frac{\pi}{\pi I_{n-1} + 4x^2} \,\textrm{d}x, \ I_\infty=$$
Here the taking of the limit is implied. The answer given was $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$. I was able to obtain a recurrence relation after solving the integral: $$I_n = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{I_{n-1}}}\tan^{-1}\left(2\sqrt{\frac{I_{n-1}}{\pi}}\right)$$
However, I'm unsure where to proceed, especially considering the nesting of the arctangent functions. Should I take $n \to \infty$ now, or should I try to solve the recurrence relation (and how should I go about it?)

Assuming the limit exists, in the limit $I_n=I_{n-1}=I_\infty$. Substitute into your recurrence relation and solve.

@Intelligentipauca Got it. Just needed to solve by inspection.

First, we assume that the sequence converges to some limit $L$, following @Intelligentipauca's suggestion. Therefore, as $n \to \infty$, $I_n \to L$ and $I_{n-1} \to L$. This gives us the equation:
$$L = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{L}} \tan^{-1}\left(2 \sqrt{\frac{L}{\pi}}\right)$$
To solve this, we make the substitution $t = \sqrt{\frac{L}{\pi}}$, which implies $L = \pi t^2$. Substituting this into the equation, we get:
$$\pi t^2 = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{t} \tan^{-1}(2t)$$
Multiplying both sides by $t$:
$$\pi t^3 = \frac{1}{2} \tan^{-1}(2t)$$
Next, we set $u = 2t$, so $t = \frac{u}{2}$. Substituting this into the equation:
$$\pi \left(\frac{u}{2}\right)^3 = \frac{1}{2} \tan^{-1}(u)$$
Simplifying:
$$\pi \frac{u^3}{8} = \frac{1}{2} \tan^{-1}(u)$$
Multiplying both sides by 8:
$$\pi u^3 = 4 \tan^{-1}(u)$$
It is easy to check that $u = 1$, $u = 0$, and $u = -1$ satisfy this equation.
However, since $I_0 = 1$ and the sequence is defined recursively with positive terms, the limit $I_\infty$ should be positive. Therefore, the valid solutions are $t = \frac{1}{2}$ and $t = -\frac{1}{2}$, both leading to $L = \frac{\pi}{4}$. (The limit would be 0 if $u=0$.)
Thus, the limit is:
$$\boxed{\frac{\pi}{4}}$$

LIMIT CANNOT BE ZERO
In what follows, I show why $L$ cannot be zero.
I analyze the behavior of the sequence $I_n$ defined by the integral:
$$ I_n = \int_{0}^{I_{n-1}} \frac{\pi}{\pi I_{n-1} + 4x^2} \, dx $$
with $I_0 = 1$. The sequence is defined by the recurrence relation:
$$ I_n = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{I_{n-1}}} \tan^{-1}\left(2 \sqrt{\frac{I_{n-1}}{\pi}}\right) $$
Assuming the sequence converges to a limit $L$, we set:
$$ L = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{L}} \tan^{-1}\left(2 \sqrt{\frac{L}{\pi}}\right) $$
For small $I_{n-1}$, we approximate the integral and find that $I_n \approx 1$, suggesting $I_n$ does not approach zero as $I_{n-1}$ approaches zero. By setting $t = \sqrt{\frac{I_{n-1}}{\pi}}$ and analyzing the limit:
$$\lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{t} \cdot \tan^{-1}(2t)$$
we find:
$$ \lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{1}{2} \cdot (2 - \frac{8t^2}{3} + \cdots) = 1$$
This indicates $I_n$ approaches 1, not zero. Therefore, $L = 0$ is not a valid limit for the sequence $I_n$.

EQUATION HAS ONLY 3 ZEROS
To show that equation $\pi u^{3}=4\tan^{-1}(u)$ has only the mentioned
solutions ($u=-1$, $u=0$, and $u=1$), I analyze the function $f(u)=\pi u^{3}-4\tan^{-1}(u)$
and its behavior.
Let me analyze its derivative:
$$
f'(u)=3\pi u^{2}-\frac{4}{1+u^{2}}
$$
Set $f'(u)=0$:
$$
3\pi u^{2}-\frac{4}{1+u^{2}}=0
$$
Multiply by $1+u^{2}$:
$$
3\pi u^{2}(1+u^{2})-4=0
$$
Let $v=u^{2}$:
$$
3\pi v^{2}+3\pi v-4=0
$$
Solve using the quadratic formula:
$$
v=\frac{-3\pi\pm\sqrt{9\pi^{2}+48\pi}}{6\pi}
$$
The solutions are $v\approx-1.3212$ and $v\approx0.32123$. Since
$v$ is not negative, we discard the first solution, and we are left
with $u\approx\pm0.57$.
Now, it is easy to check that:

As $u\to\infty$, $f(u)\to\infty$.

As $u\to-\infty$, $f(u)\to-\infty$.

Between $u=-\infty$ and $u=-1$, $f(u)$ is increasing.

Between $u=-1$ and $u=0$, $f(u)$ is increasing up to $-0.57$ and
then decreasing, which implies there is a single maximum of $f(u)$
at $u=-0.57$, that is positive as $f(-1)=f(0)=0$. This there is
no zero between $-1$ and $0$.

Between $u=0$ and $u=1$, a similar logic can be used to prove there
is no zero of $f(u)$ in this interval.

For $u>1$, $f(u)$ is increasing.


Given the behavior of $f(u)$ and its derivative, the function crosses
zero only at $u=-1$, $u=0$, and $u=1$.

That equation also has $u=0$ and $u=-1$ as solution. But it shouldn't be difficult to prove that $I_n$ is an increasing sequence.

Thanks, @Intelligentipauca! You are right! I have meanwhile also contemplated the solutions you mention in my edited solution.

You only justified $L\ge0$. Why is $L$ non-zero?

Thanks, @AnneBauval, for your comment! I have just edited a more detailed explanation why $L$ cannot be zero.

Have you justified that the $u=1$ is the unique positive solution of  $\pi u^3 = 4 \tan^{-1}(u)$ ?

Thanks, @RyszardSzwarc, for your comment! A justification can be found by analyzing $f'(u)$. Later on, I will add that analysis.

Done so, @RyszardSzwarc.

@Intelligentipauca $I_n$ is not monotonic. For more details, see Ryszard's answer.

Instead of assuming the existence of a limit, let us prove it.
$J_n:=2\sqrt\frac{I_n}\pi$ satisfies $J_0=\frac2{\sqrt\pi}\approx1.13$ and $J_n=g(J_{n-1})$, where
$$g(x)=2\sqrt\frac{\arctan x}{\pi x}.$$
A rapid inspection of the graph of $g$ (using Wolfram Alpha and Paint)

shows that $J_n$ is alternatively larger and smaller than $1$ and converges to it, hence $I_n\to\frac\pi4$.
Less handwavingly, $g=2\sqrt\frac h\pi$ where
$$h(x):=\frac{\arctan x}x\in\left[\frac1{1+x^2},1\right]$$
so
$$h'(x)=-\frac1x\left(h(x)-\frac1{1+x^2}\right),$$
hence for every positive $x$,
$$\begin{align}0<-\sqrt\pi g'(x)&=\frac{-h'(x)}{\sqrt{h(x)}}\\&=\frac{\sqrt{h(x)}}x\left(1-\frac1{(1+x^2)h(x)}\right)\\&\le\frac1x\left(1-\frac1{1+x^2}\right)\\&=\frac x{1+x^2}\\&\le\frac12\end{align}$$
hence $g$ is (decreasing on $\Bbb R_+$ and) contractive. Its (unique) fixed point is clearly $1$.

Wonderful!! (+)

I have substantially modified my answer following your idea of contractive mappings.

By substitution $x=I_{n-1}t$ we get
$$I_n=\int\limits_0^1 {1\over 1+{4\over \pi}I_{n-1}t^2} \,dt\le 1$$
Consider the function
$$g(x)=\int\limits_0^1 {1\over 1+{4\over \pi}xt^2}\,dt $$ We have $I_n=g(I_{n-1})$ and $g(\pi/4)=\pi/4.$
Moreover $$|g(x_2)-g(x_1)| ={4\over \pi}|x_2-x_1|\int\limits_0^1 {t^2\over \left (1+{4\over \pi}x_1t^2\right )\left (1+{4\over \pi}x_1t^2\right )} \,dt \\ \le |x_2-x_1|{4\over
 \pi}\int_0^1t^2\,dt= {4\over 3\pi}|x_2-x_1|$$
Hence the function $g$ is a contraction on $[0,\infty)$ (the idea of @Anne Bauval).  The sequence $I_n$ is thus convergent to the unique  fixed point of $g.$ As $g(\pi/4)=\pi/4$ the limit of $I_n$ is equal $\pi/4.$
